# Blank data for certain hours - hence missing in my array. Is there a way to fill in the missing hours?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some data by the hour and summarise/consolidate the array.

However, there are some hours which are blank in `data.Items` hence my array would skip the data point completely.

Is there a way where I can through my data/array and fill in the gaps and assign a '0' next to it?

```
  for(i=0; i<dataLength; i++){
      var date = new Date(data[i].ctimestamp);
      date.setMinutes(0);
      date.setSeconds(0);
      date.setMilliseconds(0);
      var date = moment(date).tz("Pacific/Auckland").format("DD/MM/YY HH:mm");
      dateArray.push({"date" : date});
  }
```

Here is an example - "11/12/18 05:00" and "11/12/18 06:00" are missing so it's skipped completely.

```
   [{
        "date": "11/12/18 08:00",
        "count": 5
    },
    {
        "date": "11/12/18 07:00",
        "count": 4
    },
    {
        "date": "11/12/18 04:00",
        "count": 6
    }]
```

Ideally, I would like it to show:

```
  [
        {
            "date": "11/12/18 08:00",
            "count": 5
        },
        {
            "date": "11/12/18 07:00",
            "count": 4
        },
        {
            "date": "11/12/18 06:00",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "11/12/18 05:00",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "11/12/18 04:00",
            "count": 6
        }]
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of what is in data? Also, what your actual code is doing, instead of what you want it to do?

Comment: Done - see how "11/12/18 05:00" and "11/12/18 06:00" are missing?

Comment: Ok, what is this reduce for? Is it relevant to the question?

What you want is just fill this array of objects with dates, and counts, right?

Comment: The reduce simply summaries the array and counts up the number of occurrences by date/hour.

However, if nothing happened that hour, it would simply be blank.

Comment: But is it relevant to your question? Thats what you do after you get what you want, you should only have what you are doing to get what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this simplifies the logic and produces the result you want:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "date": "11/12/18 08:00",
    "count": 5
  },
  {
    "date": "11/12/18 07:00",
    "count": 4
  },
  {
    "date": "11/12/18 04:00",
    "count": 6
  }
];

let min = Number.MAX_VALUE;
let max = 0;

const dates = data.reduce((memo, {date, count}) => {
  const time = new Date(date).getTime();
  min = Math.min(min, time);
  max = Math.max(max, time);
  memo[time] = count;
  return memo;
}, {});

const ONE_HOUR = 60 * 60 * 1000;

const dataOutput = [];

for (let i = min;i <= max;i += ONE_HOUR) {
  dataOutput.push({
    date: new Date(i).toLocaleString(), 
    count: dates[i] || 0
  });
}

console.log(dataOutput)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume the array you posted as sample data, is called dataItems. Also, I'll use moment to handle time, but you can convert it to vanilla JS if you want.

So, what I would do is go through dataItems, and check if prev value is 1 hour prev to this value, if its not, add a new input.

```
dataItems.reduce((acc, val) => {
  if(!acc) {
    return [moment(val)];
  }
  let momentVal = moment(val)
  if (momentVal.diff(acc[acc.length - 1], 'hours') !== 1){
    acc.push(momentVal)
    return acc;
  } else {
    while(momentVal.diff(acc[acc.length - 1], 'hours') !== 1){
      acc.push(moment(acc[acc.length - 1]).add(1, 'hours')) //clone and add 1 hour
    }
  }
}])
```

I didn't take in consideration your object isn't just date, but that should be simple to adapt. The general logic is: go through your array, if the previous one is 1 hour less than right now, keep it going. Else, add a new input until the actual one is 1 hour after the last one on the array

Comment: Will this have an eventual speed impact if I have a very large array? I.e thousands.

Comment: @turtlepower Well, couple options: You had a reduce function after getting the array before, merging this function with your reducer would mean minimal speed impact. If you don't merge, well, computers are pretty fast. If its just one time, it will impact in miliseconds. If you run this multiple times it can have greater impact